# sikuli runtime error in eclipse ide

Tags: java, test-automation-framework, eclipse, sikuli

i am hitting an error for the code below, this is my first time running eclipse with sikuli to automate desktop application. the image is an icon of a new folder in desktop. any help?

```
import org.sikuli.script.FindFailed;
import org.sikuli.script.Pattern;
import org.sikuli.script.Screen;
public class skulix {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FindFailed {

        Screen screen = new Screen();
        Pattern pattern = new Pattern("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\a\\a.PNG");
        screen.click(pattern);  
    }
}
```

this is the error i am hitting.

```
[error] RunTimeINIT: *** BE AWARE: Running on Java 8+ *** Please report problems ***
Exception in thread "main" FindFailed: C:/Users/User/Desktop/a/a.PNG: (94x97) in S(0)[0,0 1920x1080] E:Y, T:3.0
  Line 2761, in file Region.java

    at org.sikuli.script.Region.wait(Region.java:2761)
    at org.sikuli.script.Region.find(Region.java:2326)
    at org.sikuli.script.Region.getLocationFromTarget(Region.java:3220)
    at org.sikuli.script.Region.click(Region.java:3718)
    at org.sikuli.script.Region.click(Region.java:3703)
    at testscript.skulix.main(skulix.java:18)
```

reference image taken and used - error message

```
[error] RunTimeINIT: *** BE AWARE: Running on Java 8+ *** Please report problems ***
[error] RunTimeAPI: Problematic lib: C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Sikulix\SikulixLibs_201807110819\VisionProxy.dll (...TEMP...)
[error] RunTimeAPI: VisionProxy.dll loaded, but it might be a problem with needed dependent libraries
ERROR: ...TEMP...: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform
[error] RunTimeAPI:  *** terminating: problem with native library: VisionProxy.dll
```

using 2.0.4 jar. error message

```
Exception in thread "main" FindFailed: C:\Users\User\Desktop\a\2.png: (68x83) in R[0,0 1920x1080]@S(0)
  Line 2287, in file Region.java

    at org.sikuli.script.Region.find(Region.java:2287)
    at testscript.skulix.main(skulix.java:13)
```

Comment: take reference image using silkuli it self, the error means silkuli cannot find the pattern or image

Comment: ok, i've tried it, seems to have some issue. the error updated on my main post

Comment: are you using Maven ?

Comment: yes the script is running on maven eclipse

Comment: https://github.com/RaiMan/SikuliX1/blob/master/README.md , try using the latest version 2.1.0-SNAPSHOT or 2.0.4

Comment: getting similar error. using 2.0.4 , tried both reference image and snipping tool screenshot.

Comment: Please accept the answer by clicking the tick sign if the answer helped you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The below code works:**

```
    //open the url
    driver.get("https://www.facebook.com");
    Screen screen = new Screen();

    //##################### ONE TIME STEP STARTS ###############################

    //A overlay screen will apear that asks you to take the screen shot
    // select the area you want to capture
    ScreenImage scrImgFile = screen.userCapture();
    Pattern pattern = null;

    //THis method will save the file to the current directory
    String path = scrImgFile.getFile(".");

    //This will print the full path of the save file
    System.out.println("Please note down the file Path: ");
    System.out.println(path);

    //  rerun the program by replacing the below path with the path we got above

    //##################### ONE TIME STEP ENDS ###############################

    pattern = new Pattern("D:\\selenium_poc_java\\Selenium_basic\\.\\sikuliximage-1588144437209.png");

    try {
        screen.click(pattern);
    } catch (FindFailed e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**Code explanation:**

1. We capture the element image using the interactive mode of silkuli (userCapture())
2. We save the capture to current directory, the file name is generated randomly (getFile()
3. Note down the file path printed
4. Replace the path in pattern with the file path printed, Remove the code block between **one time step starts** and **one time step ends**. Rerun the code

**Output**

If you use Pattern(Path) then you can click any element realtime:

[image]

**For clicking Desktop applications (or any folder):**

Clcik properties and goto general tab, copy the location and paste it in `Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop"));`

```
     Screen screen = new Screen();

    //import java.awt.Desktop;
    Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop"));

    //##################### ONE TIME STEP STARTS ###############################

    //A overlay screen will apear that asks you to take the screen shot
    // select the area you want to capture
    ScreenImage scrImgFile = screen.userCapture();
    Pattern pattern = null;

    //THis method will save the file to the current directory
    String path = scrImgFile.getFile(".");

    //This will print the full path of the save file
    System.out.println("Please note down the file Path: ");
    System.out.println(path);

    //  rerun the program by replacing the below path with the path we got above

    //##################### ONE TIME STEP ENDS ###############################

    pattern = new Pattern(path);

    try {
        screen.click(pattern);
    } catch (FindFailed e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }  


}
```

**Update:**

you can use `App.open("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop");` also to open the desktop insted of using awt. This is much faster that awt.

```
import org.sikuli.script.App;
```

Comment: FindFailed: C:\Users\User\Downloads\a\sikuliximage-1588172361517.png: (72x100) in R[0,0 1920x1080]@S(0)
  Line 2222, in file Region.java , hi thanks for the help. the one time step works, however, i still hitting the error. after i replace with one time step method.

Comment: Try adding a sleep before the click

Comment: pattern = new Pattern(path); try like this and see if the code actually works

Comment: @user1579414 Added GIF showing how i selected the radio button and it clicked radio button

Comment: added 5sec sleep and having same error.. i'm trying automate  click an shortcut in my desktop which is a notepad txt...

Comment: @user1579414 When ever you ask question please make the requirement clear, i have added the step to click a desktop icon. To do this, you have to first open the desktop then only silkuli can focus on that .

Comment: ok thanks! it works, it seems like i have to open desktop folder everytime i run it.

Comment: @user1579414 please accept the answer by clicking the tick sign near to my answer

Comment: Happy that it helped

Comment: Yes , then only silkuli can focus on it , silkuli focuses on region based on pixel so it want to bring particular window to focus before working on it

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86979/359323 THis will show how to accept an answer thank you :)

Comment: import org.sikuli.script.App; also could be used to open desktop

Comment: yup ok i have ticked the answer :)

Comment: o ya i have added 1 more question which i need help, would much more appreciate it https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/44441/sikuli-verification-assertion-text-image

Answer (score 0):

****Please ensure that your Dispaly resolution as 100% and Browser Zoom % to be 100%
You can go with dependency Verison 2.0.5 or  1.1.0****